# View and preview look different for strange inner code

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview

I found the following post:

[Curved border for list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871228/curved-border-for-list-view)

that contains code in code (because there are 2 scroll bars in the same main window).

But if I access the following URL: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5871228/edit I can see that the preview looks different.

Probably view & preview must show the same thing.

The usage that generated that strange view is bizarre, but I could find it useful in some other particular situations (to simulate something like block collapsing).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, look, I edited the post a bit (removed salutation and thanks and a few unneeded br tags) and it looks absolutely different.

The issue was probably a markdown bug back in 2011, when the question was posted and edited last and which was fixed since.

Editing (as I did) re-runs the markdown processor, so any fixes would have been now applied.

Comment: Made another edit - removed the `<pre>` in favour of an *actual* code section (properly indented), the `catch` is now there. My bad.